# How do I get a count of unique characters by row with awk?

Tags: awk

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
A A A G A A
A A A A A A
G A G A G G
A G G G G G
G A A A A A
T C T C C C
A A A G A A
C C C C C C
T G G G G G
T T T T T T
```

I want to count the number of occurrences of each letter by row.  There is a fair bit of documentation on doing this by field, but not by row.  I have been thinking something like:
`for(i=1; i <= NF, i++)` to loop through the columns in each row and then make a counter variable to add occurrences to.  Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: If you set your `FS` field separator to a newline `'\n'`, can you use the documentation you've found for an easy answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In awk, I don't think there is a simpler way to iterate over the fields in a line.

```
awk '
  {
    delete a
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
      a[$i]++
    printf("%d -- ", NR)
    for (val in a)
      printf("%s:%d, ", val, a[val])
    print ""
  }
'
```

Given your input, this outputs

```
1 -- A:5, G:1, 
2 -- A:6, 
3 -- A:2, G:4, 
4 -- A:1, G:5, 
5 -- A:5, G:1, 
6 -- C:4, T:2, 
7 -- A:5, G:1, 
8 -- C:6, 
9 -- G:5, T:1, 
10 -- T:6,
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not much with awk, here's a perl version:

```
perl -ne 'my %c; $c{$_}++ for split; print scalar keys %c'
```

Output

```
212222212
```

If you prefer, add newline

```
perl -ne 'my %c; $c{$_}++ for split; print scalar keys %c . "\n"'
```

**Edit**

In reaction to the comment, perhaps this is more like what you meant:

```
perl -ne 'my %c; $c{$_}++ for split; print "$_:$c{$_} " for keys %c; print "\n"'
```

Output:

```
A:5 G:1 
A:6 
A:2 G:4 
A:1 G:5 
A:5 G:1 
T:2 C:4 
A:5 G:1 
C:6 
T:1 G:5 
T:6
```

Comment: This counts the number of distinct letters, not the number of occurrences of each letter.